# How to calculate triangle's angle

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

Following this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THlgu.jpg), I have C1, C2 and H values. How to calculate the angle?

Comment: If you have all $C_1, C_2, H$, there are lots of ways. Pick your favorite inverse trigonometric function.

Comment: Unfortunately, I feel I had to flag this. This isn’t a site that will solve problems **for** you, and some effort or examples of your own thoughts must be shown. That way, we can help you—and others—the best we can. For more information, please read [how to ask a good question](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ). At any rate, I wish the best of luck to you, and please continue to contribute to our wonderful site!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the angle you're looking for, be $\theta$. Have you come across trigonometry yet (especially inverse trigonometric functions)? You're looking for $\theta$ such that $$\tan\theta = \frac{C_2}{C_1}$$
$$\implies \theta = \arctan\frac{C_2}{C_1}$$
where $\arctan$ is just $\tan^{-1}(x) \in [-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$, i.e. the inverse function of $f(x) = \tan x$.

Comment: thank you very much